# trying to use mockMvc.perform(....content(someJson) to Test my Web-Application

Tags: spring-boot-test, mockmvc, security-testing

when using `mockMvc.perform` to Test my Web-Application I'm trying to use `.content(someJson)` to meet the requirements for the body. Unfortunately, when using `.content` it appears red with the error:

> Cannot resolve method 'content' in 'ResultActions'

The request looks like this:

```java
mockMvc
    .perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/test/url")
            .with(httpBasic(authorizedUsername, auhorizedPassword))
            .header("user", id)
            .secure(true)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(someJson),
    )
    .andExpect(status().isCreated());
```

I can't figure out why that is. Any help for a struggling colleague?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the closing clip was missplaced...